# Wildcard on Subject Alternative Name

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, storage-area-network, certificate

I have certificate issued to *.iphone.apple.com. It has *.ipod.apple.com as a SAN.

Can this be used for gen5.touch.ipod.apple.com or should *.touch.ipod.apple.com be added to *.iphone.apple.com as a SAN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wildcards only apply to a single DNS label. So `*.example.com` would only support `sub1.example.com`, but not `sub2.sub1.example.com`. So for 2nd level sub-domains you'd need a wildcard at the 1st subdomain level (`*.sub1.example.com`).

Comment: Thanks! Is this information available online somewhere?

Comment: @Sam It's all enclosed in [RFC4592](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4592) if you wish to dig through it. That applies to DNS, but the SAN inherits the 'leftmost label' constraint.